# Ошибка чтения после memcpy

Tags: c++

Visual Studio 2015. Читаю данные из потока. Задача - не выводить на экран данные, если в потоке нет изменений.
Вот код решения:

```
// MemReader.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // Имя для выделенной памяти
    TCHAR StreamName[] = TEXT("Command");
    // Создаст, или подключится к уже созданной памяти с таким именем
    HANDLE hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, StreamName);

    //Если указатель на память получен
    if (hFileMap)
    {
        BYTE b = (BYTE)0;
        PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)(MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 256));;
        PBYTE pprev = &b;

        while (true)
        {

            //Получает доступ к байтам памяти
            pb = (PBYTE)(MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 256));

            if (pprev == NULL
                || pb != pprev)
            {
                std::cout << pb << '\n';
                memcpy(pprev, pb, 256);
            }

            //Закрывает представление
            UnmapViewOfFile(pb);
        }
    }

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Первая итерация цикла проходит нормально. Но на второй итерации, в строке

```
pb = (PBYTE)(MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 256));
```

я все время получаю pb равный NULL. Если закоментировать строку:

```
memcpy(pprev, pb, 256);
```

То все работает. В смысле читает корректно, но выводит повторяющиеся строки с такой скоростью, что сложно анализировать. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А разве нужно постоянно MapViewOfFile + UnmapViewOfFile делать? Более того, если вы из MapViewOfFile получаете нулевой указать - нужно смотреть код ошибки через GetLastError().

Comment: Оформите ответ в виде ответа. У нас не совсем форум =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [Владимир Мартьянов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179402/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2). Вот верный, работающий код:

```
// MemReader.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Имя для выделенной памяти
    TCHAR StreamName[] = TEXT("Command");
    // Создаст, или подключится к уже созданной памяти с таким именем
    HANDLE hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, StreamName);

    //Если указатель на память получен
    if (hFileMap)
    {
        BYTE b = (BYTE)0;
        PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)(MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 256));;
        PBYTE pprev = &b;

        while (true)
        {
            if (pprev == NULL
                || *pb != *pprev)
            {
                std::cout << pb << '\n';
                memcpy(pprev, pb, 256);
            }
        }
        //Закрывает представление
        UnmapViewOfFile(pb);
    }

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```